# Mongo + Laravel : accessing subdocuments of subdocuments

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, laravel

I am using jenssegers mongodb package to connect Laravel with mongo and i'm trying to access to subdocuments of subdocuments in Laravel in order to delete all the data that have a certain value:
For example in here i want to delete all the subsubfamilies that have elec equals to 4.

```
family {
    "_id" = 12,
    subfamily{
         "_id" = 123,
         "name" = abcde,
         subsubfamily{
             "_id" = 1234,
             elec = 5
         },
         {
             "_id" = 5678,
             elec = 4
         }
    },
    {
         "_id" = 456,
         "name" = lmnop,
         subsubfamily{
             "_id" = 9012,
             elec = 4
         },
         {
             "_id" = 3456,
             elec = 8
         }
    }  
}
```

I tried to access the subfamily by :

```
$res= family::where('_id',12)->where('subfamily._id', 456)->project(array('subfamily.$' => 1))->get();
```

(Which return the same result as:

```
 db.collection.find({"subfamily" : {"$elemMatch" : {"subsubfamily" : {"$elemMatch" : {"_id" : 9012}}}}},{"measurements.$":1})
```

)

It returns the subfamily I want:

```
"_id" => 12
"subfamily" => array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
        "_id" => 456
        "name" => lmnop
        "subsubfamily" => array:2 [
            0 => array:2 [
               "id" => 9012
               "elec" => 4
            ]
            1 => array:2 [
               "id" => 3456
               "elec" => 8
            ]
  ]
```

But I can't figure out how to access to the subsubfamily. I'd like something like this :

```
"subsubfamily" => array:1 [
            0 => array:2 [
               "id" => 9012
               "elec" => 4
            ]
```

And then I'll be able to delete it.

```
$res= family::where('_id',12)->where('subsubfamily._id', 9012)->project(array('subfamily.$' => 1))->get();
```

Not working.

```
$res= family::where('_id',12)->where('subfamily._id', 456)->where('subsubfamily._id', 9012)->project(array('subfamily.subsubfamily' => 1))->get();
```

Not working either.

Anyone can help?